# Using C# to reference a port number to service name

Tags: c#, ruby, mono, port

On Linux using MONO.

How do I use C# to pair a port number to a service ?

example:

```
port 80 = http
port 443 = https
```

and output it to the console, I need this for a simple port scanner I built.

I know this function exists in ruby:

```
Socket.getservbyport(80, "tcp")
```

Comment: You could try parsing `%WINDIR%\System32\drivers\etc\services` but I'm not sure if there's an API function for it (if there is, I suspect it'll only be Win32 API, not .NET)

Comment: well, if I may add I'm using Linux as in mono(C#) so that wont help me, but I'm sure they have a built in function for that.

Comment: Turns out the Win32 API has exactly the same name as the ruby one - [`getservbyport`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738541(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Mono Linux version**

I had a bit of time on my hands so set up Mono on my Ubuntu Linux box to test with. The Mono PInvoke implementation of getservbyport() and getservbyname() is simpler than on Windows (just load libc which has the networking stuff built in). Here's the example code for reference in case anyone ever wants it ;)

```
namespace SocketUtil
{
    using System;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;

    [Serializable]
    public class SocketUtilException : Exception
    {

        public SocketUtilException()
        {
        }

        public SocketUtilException(string message)
            : base(message)
        {
        }

        public SocketUtilException(string message, Exception inner)
            : base(message, inner)
        {
        }

        protected SocketUtilException(
            SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
            : base(info, context)
        {
        }
    }

    public static class SocketUtil
    {

        [StructLayoutAttribute(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct servent
        {
            public string s_name;
            public IntPtr s_aliases;
            public ushort s_port;
            public string s_proto;
        }


        [DllImport("libc", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        private static extern IntPtr getservbyname(string name, string proto);
        [DllImport("libc", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        private static extern IntPtr getservbyport(ushort port, string proto);

        public static string GetServiceByPort(ushort port, string protocol, out List<string> aliases)
        {
            var netport = unchecked((ushort)IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder(unchecked((short)port)));
            var result = getservbyport(netport, protocol);
            if (IntPtr.Zero == result)
            {
                throw new SocketUtilException(
                    string.Format("Could not resolve service for port {0}", port));
            }
            var srvent = (servent)Marshal.PtrToStructure(result, typeof(servent));
            aliases = GetAliases(srvent);
            return srvent.s_name;

        }

        private static List<string> GetAliases(servent srvent)
        {
            var aliases = new List<string>();
            if (srvent.s_aliases != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                IntPtr cb;

                for (var i = 0;
                    (cb = Marshal.ReadIntPtr(srvent.s_aliases, i)) != IntPtr.Zero;
                    i += Marshal.SizeOf(cb))
                {
                    aliases.Add(Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(cb));
                }
            }
            return aliases;
        }

        public static ushort GetServiceByName(string service, string protocol, out List<string> aliases)
        {

            var result = getservbyname(service, protocol);
            if (IntPtr.Zero == result)
            {
                throw new SocketUtilException(
                    string.Format("Could not resolve port for service {0}", service));
            }

            var srvent = (servent)Marshal.PtrToStructure(result, typeof(servent));
            aliases = GetAliases(srvent);
            var hostport = IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder(unchecked((short)srvent.s_port));
            return unchecked((ushort)hostport);

        }
    }
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            try
            {
                List<string> aliases;
                var port = SocketUtil.GetServiceByName("https", "tcp", out aliases);

                Console.WriteLine("https runs on port {0}", port);
                foreach (var alias in aliases)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(alias);
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Reverse call:{0}", SocketUtil.GetServiceByPort(port, "tcp", out aliases));

            }
            catch (SocketUtilException exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(exception.Message);
                if (exception.InnerException != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(exception.InnerException.Message);
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: as this is a fully implemented in MONO & there is no need to copy files over from windows this is for me the Answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Windows Version**

Update: Saw too late that poster had added a Linux and Mono tag after asking the question so wrote a Windows implementation. On Linux use the Mono version in the second post.

Mohammad's solution is more portable than the alternative in many ways. getservbyname() and getservbyport() are platform-dependent and require using P/Invoke to use with c# on Windows and most likely on Mono as well.

To implement the code below in Mono you'll need to PInvoke using the platform specific APIs (the header would be netdb.h) - note that WSAStartUp() and WSACleanUp() are windows-specific socket initialization functions which are irrelevant on a Linux system. Don't have mono setup at the moment so can't provide a linux-specific solution but if you're willing to jump through the hoops here's a windows (32-bit) example to base your code on:

```
namespace SocketTest
{
    using System;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Net.Sockets;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;



    [Serializable]
    public class SocketUtilException : Exception
    {

        public SocketUtilException()
        {
        }

        public SocketUtilException(string message)
            : base(message)
        {
        }

        public SocketUtilException(string message, Exception inner)
            : base(message, inner)
        {
        }

        protected SocketUtilException(
            SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
            : base(info, context)
        {
        }
    }
    public static class SocketUtil
    {
        private const int WSADESCRIPTION_LEN = 256;

        private const int WSASYSSTATUS_LEN = 128;

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct WSAData
        {
            public short wVersion;
            public short wHighVersion;

            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = WSADESCRIPTION_LEN+1)]
            public string szDescription;

            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = WSASYSSTATUS_LEN+1)]
            public string wSystemStatus;
            [Obsolete("Ignored when wVersionRequested >= 2.0")]
            public ushort wMaxSockets;
            [Obsolete("Ignored when wVersionRequested >= 2.0")]
            public ushort wMaxUdpDg;
            public IntPtr dwVendorInfo;
        }


        [StructLayoutAttribute(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct servent
        {
            public string s_name;
            public IntPtr s_aliases;
            public short s_port;
            public string s_proto;
        }

        private static ushort MakeWord ( byte low, byte high)
        {

            return  (ushort)((ushort)(high << 8) | low);
        }

        [DllImport("ws2_32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern int WSAStartup(ushort wVersionRequested, ref WSAData wsaData);
        [DllImport("ws2_32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern int WSACleanup();
        [DllImport("ws2_32.dll",  SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        private static extern IntPtr getservbyname(string name, string proto);
        [DllImport("ws2_32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        private static extern IntPtr getservbyport(short port, string proto);

        public static string GetServiceByPort(short port, string protocol)
        {

            var wsaData = new WSAData();
            if (WSAStartup(MakeWord(2, 2), ref wsaData) != 0)
            {
                throw new SocketUtilException("WSAStartup",
                    new SocketException(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()));

            }
            try
            {
                var netport = Convert.ToInt16(IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder(port));
                var result = getservbyport(netport, protocol);
                if (IntPtr.Zero == result)
                {
                    throw new SocketUtilException(
                        string.Format("Could not resolve service for port {0}", port),
                        new SocketException(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()));
                }
                var srvent = (servent)Marshal.PtrToStructure(result, typeof(servent));
                return srvent.s_name;;
            }
            finally
            {
                WSACleanup();
            }
        }


        public static short GetServiceByName(string service, string protocol)
        {

            var wsaData = new WSAData();
            if(WSAStartup(MakeWord(2,2), ref wsaData) != 0)
            {
                throw new SocketUtilException("WSAStartup", 
                    new SocketException(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()));

            }
            try
            {
                var result = getservbyname(service, protocol);
                if (IntPtr.Zero == result)
                {
                    throw new SocketUtilException(
                        string.Format("Could not resolve port for service {0}", service), 
                        new SocketException(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()));
                }
                var srvent = (servent)Marshal.PtrToStructure(result, typeof(servent));
                return Convert.ToInt16(IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder(srvent.s_port));
            }
            finally
            {
                WSACleanup();
            }



        }
    }
    class Program
    {


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            try
            {


                var port = SocketUtil.GetServiceByName("http", "tcp");
                Console.WriteLine("http runs on port {0}", port);

                Console.WriteLine("Reverse call:{0}", SocketUtil.GetServiceByPort(port, "tcp"));



            }
            catch(SocketUtilException exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(exception.Message);
                if(exception.InnerException != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(exception.InnerException.Message);
                }
            }


        }
    }
```

Comment: This does look good but as it is WAY over my league i will go with 

Mohammad's answer.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows there is a "services" file which is located at System32\Drivers\Etc\ folder. I have written the following code to parse it. You can use it to find information on any port you want:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var services = ReadServicesFile();

        // For example, I want to find information about port 443 of TCP service
        var port443Info = services.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Port == 443 && s.Type.Equals("tcp"));

        if (port443Info != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("TCP Port = {0}, Service name = {1}", port443Info.Port, port443Info.Name);
        }

    }

    static List<ServiceInfo> ReadServicesFile()
    {
        var sysFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System);
        if (!sysFolder.EndsWith("\\"))
            sysFolder += "\\";

        var svcFileName = sysFolder + "drivers\\etc\\services";

        var lines = File.ReadAllLines(svcFileName);

        var result = new List<ServiceInfo>();
        foreach (var line in lines)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(line) || line.StartsWith("#"))
                continue;

            var info = new ServiceInfo();

            var index = 0;

            // Name
            info.Name = line.Substring(index, 16).Trim();
            index += 16;

            // Port number and type
            var temp = line.Substring(index, 9).Trim();
            var tempSplitted = temp.Split('/');

            info.Port = ushort.Parse(tempSplitted[0]);
            info.Type = tempSplitted[1].ToLower();

            result.Add(info);
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

You will also need the following class declaration:

```
class ServiceInfo
{
    public ushort Port { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I've also realized that the 'services' file shipped with Windows 7 is more complete than Windows XP version. So you may want to have that file along with your port scanner and parse that one instead of Windows' version.

Comment: This is a good answer and I will try to copy this file to my Linux machine and use it, I would have accepted this answer but this is more of an HACK then a real option for Linux, I added more information to my question so I wont get people work hard for nothing, sry.

Comment: @Ba7a7chy Since common ports are registered by IANA, there should be no difference between them on Windows and Linux. So you can use the same file on each OS. Why you believe this is a hack?

Comment: Because the file described can be found only in windows, am I wrong?

"On Windows there is a "services" file which is located at System32\Drivers\Etc\ folder"

Comment: I believe /etc/services would be what you want (of course it depends on how linux is setup on the host machine).

Comment: @Ba7a7chy I mean you can distribute the Windows services file with your application and parse it. Service names are similar on both operating systems.

Comment: Even thou it is not the ideal thing i had in mind (ruby is so much better in that aspect) I do agree this does work, accepting answer.